# logback condition not working

Tags: java, gradle, logback, logback-classic

I'm trying to define a logback.xml that sets loglevel to INFO in PROD Environment, all other environments to DEBUG. 
Therefore we have an environment variable ENV, that is set to "PROD" on PROD Environment.
My logback.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"} [%thread] %-5level %logger %mdc - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="aiAppender" class="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logback.ApplicationInsightsAppender" />

<!-- Choose INFO level on PROD, DEBUG on other environments -->
<property name="logLevel" value="DEBUG" />
<if condition='property("ENV").contains("PROD")'>
    <then>
        <property name="logLevel" value="INFO" />
    </then>
</if>

<root level="${logLevel}">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

It should set the property "logLevel" to INFO if ENV is set to PROD. Unfortunately this doesn't work - no matter if I set the property on environment level (windows: SET ENV=PROD) or at java vm level with -D.

Any idea what I could have done wrong?

update: I found that according to the documentation the janino library has to be on the classpath. adding a  and looking at the logs also turns out that this seems to be the problem:

```
09:50:06,127 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.conditional.IfAction - Could not find Janino library on the class path. Skipping conditional processing.
```

Unfortunately even if I add it to my gradle dependencies this message keeps appearing. This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api
    compileOnly group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'

    api group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-core', version: '1.0.7'
    api group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-web', version: '1.0.7'
    api group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-logging-logback', version: '1.0.7'
    api group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
    api group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.2.3'
    api group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'

    api group: 'org.codehaus.janino', name: 'janino', version: '3.0.6'
    api group: 'org.codehaus.janino', name: 'commons-compiler', version: '3.0.6'


    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
}
```

Any idea why janino is still not found on the classpath?

Comment: Could you try to structure this as an `if` - `then`-`else` ? If PROD then loglevel = PROD, else loglevel = DEBUG .

Comment: This was my first try - didn't work either.

Comment: I'm in the early stages of researching a similar problem, which seems to have come up when we updated from logback 1.1.10 to 1.2.3. Which version are you using? (And have you found a solution to your problem?)

Answer (score 4):

If you have logback version `1.2.3` you need janino version `3.1.2`. Additionally, for me the `compile` wasn't enough.

```
implementation group: 'org.codehaus.janino', name: 'janino', version: '3.1.2'
```

Side note: `commons-compiler` is not really needed for conditions.